# Should I enable SR-IOV and/or ASPM in bios, on my ESXi server?

Tags: bios, virtualization, virtual-host, vmware-server, esxi5.5

Relevant server setup is a SuperMicro X10SRi-F with the VM store via iSCSI LUN (not internal disks). I'm running desktop VMs (among others), so I have an nVidia Quadro 6000 + ESXi 5.5, the latest that supports vSGA, as I can't afford GRID and video needs are lightweight. At the moment there arent any shared devices I can think of apart from the video card, and at most a couple of  passthrough devices, but perhaps I'm not aware of all the devices used.

SuperMicro's BIOS has a wide range of features, including SR-IOV (clearly virtualisation related) and ASPM.

I can look up what SR-IOV and ASPM (which it seems to depend on?)  *are*, but it's at a sort of 'dictionary definition' level and I'm having difficulty figuring out their implications, which would help me to decide whether or not it's beneficial for, and I *should*, enable them for my scenario.

Comment: *figuring out their implications* ...this is answerable.  *whether or not I should enable them*...this is somewhat subjective and it's best that we not be tasked with answering it. Instead, armed with an answer to the first question you should decide for yourself. Consider editing your question accordingly.

Comment: AFAIR, SR-IOV allows you to perform migration of your VMs without being tied up to host's hardware and increases the flexibility of I/O hardware by distributing available throughput. In this case server core will perform all I/O operations with virtual functions assigned to separate VMs by itself, thus not interrupting any other cores, that are involved with another VMs.


Active-State Power Management just enables the power saving of PCI Express buses.


However I don't know for sure how it will affect on your particular scenario.